# Opposite/inverse of percentage calculation

Tags: terminology, percentages

I'm sorry if this is already answered! I don't know the terminology.

If I have a sequence of categorical observations:

```
{a: 100, b: 20, c: 30}
```

I can calculate percentage for each category as `category / sum(all categories)`. This would give me:

```
{a: 0.666.., b: 0.133.., c: 0.2}
```

What I am unclear on is what the calculation `sum(all categories) / category` would be. Which would produce:

```
{a: 1.5, b: 7.5, c: 5}
```

What do you call this? I'd think 'inverse frequency', or something like that. Searching for that wasn't helpful.

Comment: The problems we want to solve generally come first.  Definitions and formula are derived in order to solve those problems.  If something isn't named such as in this case, that usually implies that it is generally not something that is useful for any problems we actually want to solve.  I know of no reason to name nor reason to use the calculations you ask about.

Comment: Indeed, no general term immediately comes to my mind for this. Perhaps more context would help?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I went back and looked at the wider context of the calculation and realised that it is a simplification of multiple steps. Specifically, the reciprocal of percentage.